# How do I sort some HTML elements alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
function render() {
  let lastContact = listadeContatos.slice(-1);
  boxapp__contact.innerHTML += lastContact
    .map((contact) => {
return `<div class="box-app__contacts-list" id=${
        contact.id
      } onclick="boxapp(this.id)">
        <div class="contact__nameinitial">${contact.fistName[0].toUpperCase()}</div>
        <div class="contact__name">${contact.fistName}</div>
      </div>`;
    }).join("");
  const contacts = document.querySelector(".box-app__contacts-list");
  const c = [...document.querySelectorAll(".contact__name")];
  if (listadeContatos.length > 1) {
    c.sort((a, b) => (a.innerText > b.innerText ? 1 : -1)).forEach((node) => {
      contacts.appendChild(node);
    });
  }
}
```

I made a simple app, a list of contacts, and I wanted them to be sorted alphabetically when a new
contact is added and called for rendering, but nothing I've tried has worked. And the similar issues I encountered were not enough for me to find the way to a solution. I'm still learning Javascript. I would like someone to help me if they can. And sorry if there are any spelling mistakes. I'm using Google Translate to make this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this sort function: `c.sort((a, b) => (a.innerText < b.innerText? -1 : a.innerText > b.innerText? 1 : 0))`

Comment: I think c.sort( (a, b) => a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText) ); would work.

Comment: yeah..it should work

Comment: localeCompare works in a way, but for example when the name Andrey needs to come before a name like Brandon, both are rendered in the same space, so Brandon doesn't assume the container below nor the initials of the names, displayed in the div of class nameinitial, are overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Have a function that sorts array of objects with `.sort()` and `.localeCompare()` first, then render the HTML with a seperate function. If the data is changed in any way, you use those two functions the same way every time. This pattern is less error prone as long as the data doesn't vary in keys or pattern.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const contactData = [{
  firstName: "Brandon",
  lastName: "Grewe",
  phone: ["205-116-8677", "961-849-8402", "112-125-1509"],
  email: ["sgrewe0@rediff.com"]
}, {
  firstName: "Lyndsay",
  lastName: "Courtes",
  phone: ["559-585-5161", "244-413-5832", "467-871-0638"],
  email: ["lcourtes1@sun.com"]
}, {
  firstName: "Rose",
  lastName: "Xavier",
  phone: ["293-858-6159"],
  email: ["gpopley2@uol.com.br", "gpopley2@npr.org"]
}, {
  firstName: "Berni",
  lastName: "Molen",
  phone: ["944-271-6491", "911-107-2055", "429-553-3494"],
  email: ["bmolen3@gnu.org"]
}, {
  firstName: "Rose",
  lastName: "Fereday",
  phone: ["820-272-1567"],
  email: ["rfereday4@naver.com"]
}, {
  firstName: "Juliana",
  lastName: "Fredi",
  phone: ["268-283-9358", "981-219-0701", "326-164-3537"],
  email: ["jfredi5@bigcartel.com", "jfredi5@exblog.jp"]
}, {
  firstName: "Barry",
  lastName: "Gatchel",
  phone: ["762-132-3931", "840-627-2075", "654-204-6164"],
  email: ["mgatchel6@com.com"]
}, {
  firstName: "Jeth",
  lastName: "Harwin",
  phone: ["871-777-0358", "968-282-0040"],
  email: ["jharwin7@yahoo.co.jp", "jharwin7@icq.com"]
}, {
  firstName: "Ahmad",
  lastName: "Scoon",
  phone: ["392-928-5655"],
  email: ["ascoon8@ask.com", "ascoon8@nyu.edu"]
}, {
  firstName: "Kristine",
  lastName: "Sleet",
  phone: ["104-606-6882"],
  email: ["ksleet9@fc2.com", "ksleet9@php.net"]
}];

// Pass in an array of objects
function arrange(array) {
  // Returns an object of arrays -- each keyed to a letter A-Z
  let letters = Object.fromEntries(
    [...new Array(26)]
      .map((_, i) => i + 65)
      .map(n => [String.fromCharCode(n), []])
    );
  //console.log(letters);
  /*
  Takes the given array and gets the first letter of each firstName 
  property then finds the array with that letter inside the letters 
  object and adds the current object to it's array -- once in 
  the array, it is sorted alphabetically by firstName or 
  lastName should firstName be identical
  */
  array.forEach(con => {
    let alpha = con.firstName.charAt(0);
    letters[alpha].push(con)
    letters[alpha].sort(
      (a, b) => a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName) == 0 ? 
        a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName) : 
        a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName)
     )
  });
  //console.log(letters);
  // Filters out any letters that have empty arrays
  letters = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(letters)
    .filter(sub => sub[1].length > 0)
  );
  //console.log(letters);
  return letters;
}

// Pass in the object returned from arrange() and an optional DOM object
function build(object, node = document.body) {
  /*
  For each key of object render a <fieldset> and add the letter 
  to it's <legend> and it's #id
  */
  Object.keys(object).forEach(letter => {
    const alphabet = `
      <fieldset id='${letter}' class='letter'>
        <legend>${letter}</legend>
      </fieldset>`;
    node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', alphabet);
  });
  // Make an array of the <fieldset>s
  const letters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.letter')];
  /*
  For each <fieldset> find the array of the object that 
  corresponds to the <fieldset>'s #id. For each object of the 
  sub-array interpolate the object's data within the template 
  literals, then render the template literal to the current <fieldset>
  */
  letters.forEach(az => {
    let group = object[az.id].map(contact => {
      const fullName = `
        <fieldset class='contact'>
          <legend>
            ${contact.firstName}
            ${contact.lastName}
          </legend>
          <menu>`;
      const numbers = contact.phone.map(tel => `
        <li>Phone: 
          <output name='phone'>${tel}</output>
        </li>`
      ).join('');
      const address = contact.email.map(pop => `
        <li>Email: 
          <output name='email'>${pop}</output>
        </li>`
      ).join('');
      return `${fullName}${numbers}
             </menu><menu>${address}</menu>
           </fieldset>`;
    });
    az.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', group.join(''));
  });
}

const data = arrange(contactData);
build(data);
```